# Extracting phrases from text Doc

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and I would appreciate some help if you can spare some time!I managed to parse a PDF from my school's site into a .text doc using iText.Now my goal is to essentially extract key phrases from the plain text.

A sample from my plain text

```
Select 1: 3 hrs 
Suggested  ANT 2000  General Anthropology or 3 hrs 
Suggested  PSY 2012  General Psychology or 3 hrs 
Suggested  SYG 2000  Introduction to Sociology  3 hrs 

4. Core Requirements: Advanced Level (49 hrs) 
Primary Core 15 hrs 
ACG 3131  Intermediate Financial Accounting I  3 hrs 
ECO 3411  Quantitative Business Tools II  3 hrs 
FIN 3403  Business Finance  3 hrs 
MAN 3025  Management of Organizations  3 hrs 
MAR 3023  Marketing  3 hrs
```

These pieces are taken from separate locations in the text file.How would I go about extracting phrases such as ECO,AGC,FIN etc.I plan on moving this program to more text docs for different majors with different course extensions, meaning that the course extensions(ECO,AGC,FIN,etc)will all stay the same but the four digits that come after it will change according to classes.

Is there a way to essentially make a dictionary of some sort including all possible class types such as ECO,AGC,FIN,etc and then grab their unique four digit extensions and maybe even rank them from lowest hrs to highest hrs?

Thanks so much for checking out my post.All help is appreciated.

Comment: If this question isn't a duplicate, then please show us your attempt code and tell us in fair detail what problems you are having with it.

Comment: Can I ask you what this is for? If you can get help from the school's IT (the person who made the site) then you could ask him for something easier to parse. Like a JSON or XML file . Otherwise you may have to look at regex  http://regexr.com/ and try to extract phrases matching  "3 letters followed by numbers then the name then the hours" (try making a regex for that )

Comment: Try this http://regexr.com/3eusu I tried to make a regex for your needs

Comment: Your question is not about iText, because you already say yourself that you have successfully done the text extraction. So the iText tag isn't needed.